# How to remove "brand" and "product code" from "product details" on product page?

Tags: magento-1.9, frontend, product-page

On the product page of my Magento website there is this block called "Poduct Details". In this block there is the availability, the brand and the code of the product you're viewing. 
Now I want to remove the Title of the block & the brand & the product code. Only I have no clue how to do this.

Below, I added a screenshot. Basically, I want to remove everything in the red circle, *except for the green part*, so the availability.

Is this even possible, and if yes, how?

Thanks in advance.

[image: The problem]

Answer (score 1):

go to Catalog > Attributes > Manage attributes. Find the attributr you'd like to hide, then scroll down a bit, you should see something like "Show on product page" with a Yes/no select. Select "No", save, clear cache if need be, there you go.

Comment: They're not attributes. Also I can't disable the header in my attributes. I want to remove also the "Product Details" header (see the red circle in the screenshot).
In the ideal situation I'd have the product name, then the price, then the availability and then the description.

Comment: How can they not be attributes? Where (in the admin product page) do you find the brand for a given product? I'm pretty sure "Product Code" is for the product's sku.

Comment: Yeah, that seemed weird to me too. But there is no "brand" attribute in my attribute management, and SKU is just SKU and not set as 'Product Code'. But I figured there has to be a way to exclude the whole block of information, I just don't know how.

Comment: What I meant by that is, "where are they stored on the admin product page, under which section?". I guess you could take a look at `app/design/frontend/XXX/YYY/layout/catalog.xml` and then look for that specific block.

Comment: Can't find them anywhere on the admin product page. It's like they're standard attributes that have been deleted, but still show up on the frontend.

Comment: Then go to the view.phtml, there should be a call to a child template, which will be referred to in the catelog.xml, you should be able to comment it there (or directly in the .phtml).